# Spring Data Neo4j corrupted json

Tags: neo4j

I'm using neo4j with spring data, when I store an object with inside a relation I get as a result of the findAll a corrupted json. I never get this error when I query the objects one at time.
Even more strange the first one in the list is correct but the second has this error. The error is at the edge field. Any idea?

```
[{
          "uuid" : "e5c90af5-6259-4ddf-ae1f-c0cff5a41296",
          "name" : "test",
          "createdBy" : {
            "uuid" : "319535cc-288f-4a23-bc02-a3b01bf6e93f",
            "createdAt" : "2017-03-10T02:06:55.925+0000",
            "user" : {
              "uuid" : "9e91032e-a54d-4297-8a6a-1506589b7529",
            },
            "edge" : { "id" : 6514
            },
            "graphId" : 664
          }
    },
    {
          "uuid" : "e5c90af5-6259-4ddf-ae1f-c0cff5a41296",
          "name" : "test",
          "createdBy" : {
            "uuid" : "319535cc-288f-4a23-bc02-a3b01bf6e93f",
            "createdAt" : "2017-03-10T02:06:55.925+0000",
            "user" : {
              "uuid" : "9e91032e-a54d-4297-8a6a-1506589b7529",
            },
            "edge" : { : 6514
            },
            "graphId" : 664
          }
    }]
```